# AIDE IDE errors not going away even after deleting full line

Tags: android, aide-ide

I'm working on an Android project. I started it in Android Studio, then moved it to Github and cloned the repo using the AIDE IDE.

After opening the Project, I got an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFhY3.jpg) in the build.gradle file.

I deleted the whole line of code, because I wasn't interested in using Constraint Layout for my app, but the error message remained the same, and it even continued marking the same line as the source of the problem.

The problem only appears in AIDE, not in Android Studio.

I have not idea why this is happening or even where to start looking.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: try cleaning the project

Comment: @Avinash Would you mind telling me how I can do that?

Comment: Go to build in Android studio and clean project

Comment: @AvinashRoy The problem is appearing in AIDE, not Anddroid Studio. The code works fine Android Studio.

Comment: sry no idea about aide

Comment: @Avinash No problem, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Or delete the file in the github project and clone it again in AIDE. This works for me sometimes. Or try

```
More... > Menu > Project > Refresh Build
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by deleting the line with the error and reopening the project.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried all and nothing worked, then connect your phone to the internet (needed) and try:

```
    More... > Settings > Build & Run > Refresh Maven Repository
```